# Setting a default value to existing field with null value - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have column in the database with value as null and i wanted 
all the existing record with that column to be filled with the default
value as 1.

Kindly help

Answer (score 3):

```
update yourtable set yourcolumn = 1 where yourcolumn is null;
```